# Unity3d - Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

Hi everyone I am new to unity3d with the webplayer and I am out of nowhere seeing this error. "You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found." I started created the project. Then added a plane object attached with the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class GoogleMap : MonoBehaviour {
public string url ="http://www.philippines.hvu.nl/_derived/maps.htm_txt_PhilMap.gif";
IEnumerator Start () {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
}}
```

I actually wanted to put a google map on the plane but for the main that url I used. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html
> But it is strange that even when I put crossdomain.xml in the root of the web site, it still has the same error. My crossdomain.xml is in UTF-8 encoding and without BOM.

encoding of crossdomain.xml must be ASCII and you must place this file at the root of your website.
summary crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

at all, your link http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html describes al details, so thanks)

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html

But it is strange that even when I put crossdomain.xml in the root of the web site, it still has the same error. My crossdomain.xml is in UTF-8 encoding and without BOM.